# Homebrew MariaDB Server Start Error with 'mysql.server start'

Tags: mariadb, mac-os-x

When starting MariaDB 10.3.8 on MacOS 10.13.6 the following strange behavior occurs:

```
mac:~user$ mysql.server start

Starting MariaDB
```

`.180813 17:50:11 mysqld_safe Logging to` `'/usr/local/var/mysql/mbp.local.err'.`

```
180813 17:50:11 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql.. ERROR!
```

There are actually many more dots in the output before ERROR! is displayed; the process takes a couple of minutes. The odd thing is the server does run. And shutdown appears normal:

```
mac:~user$ mysql.server stop

Shutting down MariaDB.. SUCCESS!
```

Any idea how to determine what is causing the error message on startup and fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue. **Don't use `mysql.server start` in macOS**.

If you installed MariaDB with `homebrew`, use `brew services` to start and stop the database. It takes only a second and doesn't write strange error to stdout.

```
brew services stop mariadb
Stopping `mariadb`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `mariadb` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mariadb)

brew services start mariadb
==> Successfully started `mariadb` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mariadb)
```

overview of services in homebrew:

```
brew services list
Name     Status  User     Plist
logstash stopped
mariadb  started Kim /Users/Kim/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
mysql    stopped
```

general help

```
brew services --help
brew services command:
    Integrates Homebrew formulae with macOS' launchctl manager.

    [sudo] brew services list
    List all running services for the current user (or root)

    [sudo] brew services run formula|--all
    Run the service formula without starting at login (or boot).

    [sudo] brew services start formula|--all
    Start the service formula immediately and register it to launch at login (or boot).

    [sudo] brew services stop formula|--all
    Stop the service formula immediately and unregister it from launching at login (or boot).

    [sudo] brew services restart formula|--all
    Stop (if necessary) and start the service immediately and register it to launch at login (or boot).

    [sudo] brew services cleanup
    Remove all unused services.

    If sudo is passed, operate on /Library/LaunchDaemons (started at boot).
    Otherwise, operate on ~/Library/LaunchAgents (started at login).
```

Comment: Thank you.  I traced the source of the error to ~/.my.cnf.  The contents of which are: 
`[client]
user=myuser
password=mypwd
database=mydb`

Moving the file eliminates the startup error.

Comment: This does not work in a multi-user environment where the brew owner is not the one wanting to start the server.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by changing .my.cnf from:

```
[client]
user=myname
password=mypwd
database=mydb
```

to:

```
[client]
user=myname
password=mypwd

[mysql]
database=mydb
```